# Como bloquear número ocupados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo problemita que me surge en mi sistema de reserva de cuartos, resulta que mi sistema hotelero reserva el número de cuarto elegido, pero cuando otro usuario entre y quiera reservar vea ese número de cuarto ocupado o que no se pueda seleccionar.

Les dejo el código completo [Hotelito.rar](http://www.mediafire.com/file/td8cp8a1db71djy/Hotelito.rar)

[image: Captura de pantalla]

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>No. de habitación *</label>
  <select name="nroom" class="form-control" required>
    <option value selected ></option>
    <option value="1" "">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option> 
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: hola sería ideal que agregues por ejemplo la consulta donde el usuario puede visualizar esa información pero el codigo y pegarlo justo aquí

Comment: ya puse el código..

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tu select es estatico(Siempre aparece la misma información). Lo que tienes que hacer es:

1.-Realizar una consulta a tu BD para extraer las habitaciones ocupadas
2.-Almacenalas en un Arreglo
3.-Generar tus options en un ciclo donde, si el valor de la iteración actual No esta dentro del arreglo se genera el option.

Saludos Espero haberte dado una idea para resolver tu problema

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para dar mejores respuestas en el futuro. Saludos.